# Can this javascript function be put into ajax? and how?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to put this into ajax so everytime a person clicks a button in jquery, it creates a php session. Is it possible just using this?

```
var milisec=00;
var seconds=60; 
function display(){ 
    if (milisec<=0){ 
       milisec=9 
       seconds-=1 
    } 
    if (seconds<=-1){ 
       milisec=0 
       seconds+=1
    } 
    else {
       milisec-=1 
       document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML= seconds+":"+"0"+milisec+"s";
       setTimeout(display,100) 
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
       document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML=  "0"+seconds+":"+"0"+milisec+"s";
    }
} 
display()
```

I need to post the time it took for them to get to the next page using Php sessions, using ajax.

Comment: what do you want to send to the server?

Comment: Please use `setTimeout(display, 100)` instead of `setTimeout('display()', 100)` - implicit `eval()`s are evil...

Comment: Why do you need ajax? Only jquery is enough.

Comment: Joseph, I want to make a php session of how long it took them to click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var seconds = 60;
  var milisec = 0;
  var stop_counter = false;    

  function display(){ 

    if(milisec == 0)      
      seconds = seconds - 1;

    milisec = milisec - 1;

    if(milisec == -1)
      milisec = 10;        

    $('#counter').html((seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds + ":0" +milisec+ "s");        

    if( (seconds == 0 && milisec == 0 && stop_counter == true) == false )
      setTimeout(function(){ display(); }, 100);

  }     


  $(document).ready(function(){

    display();

    $('#button').click(function(){

      $.post('myphpfile.php', {time : $('#counter').text()}, function(data){

        alert('Data from myphpfile.php: ' + data);
        stop_counter = true; //stop counter now

      });

    });

  });
```

myphpfile.php

```
echo 'you clicked button when counter was ' . $_POST['time'];
//you can do any php stuff here
```

this code should do what you want but I did not test it.

function $.post() from [jQuery library](http://docs.jquery.com) will pass your data to php script and also can retrieve some data which you can display on your site or something.

btw, one second has 1000 miliseconds, not 100

> sorry for my english

Comment: Instead of looping while there is no data, I would use the callback which is fired after the AJAX request is fired. Calling `display()` in that function will allow you to delete the whole code with the timeout and the detection if there is already data available.

Comment: how would you display counter for user then?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part that he wants to have a counter. Anyway I don't know if displaying counter is that useful when doing something in a short interval. If he still wants his counter then my comment is useless - sorry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by passing the value of `"seconds" and "milisec"` in the ajax call by

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#button').click(function(){
      $.post('session_file.php', {secs : seconds,millisecs:milisec}, function(data){
      });
     });
 });
```

So in the session_file.php you can write the values of the variables of `secs and millisecs`  in a session